# Copy column A f/ sheet1 to sheet 2 if column D in sheet1 <> blank

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a set of over 100 rows in Sheet1 that I would like to copy to Sheet2 but only if Column D (in Sheet1) is NOT blank.  This is basically copying information from an estimate sheet (Sheet1) with multiple rows that may or may not be used, to a new Sheet (Sheet2) which ends up being the contract sheet.

So, the goal is to only copy rows that have been used in the estimating process instead of the rows that got ignored.

This is what I used so far and worked except that every line I paste this in on Sheet2 ends up being blank IF the row was blank.

**Formula pasted in Sheet2:**

`=IF(Sheet1!D13<>"", Sheet1!A13, "")`

I would assume I would somehow replace the "" with something like "else skip to next line and don't make this a blank line" but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote but anyway both answers so far give same results from what I have.  On the results sheet, if I use my solution or the 2 others the list goes as shown above in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:A,NOT(isblank(Sheet1!D:D)))
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  Before it didn't work because when I pasted your code on Sheet 2, I had other attempted code below the line I pasted pnuts solution into, so there was a conflict.  If anyone else tries this, wipe out any code you had tried before and pasted into the cell you want the data to list in (and below that cell).

Comment: You are exactly correct.  Basically, I assumed with 23.8k points you would be correct and I simply applied your solution incorrectly.  So I wiped out my code entirely and pasted 1 line with your code.  This might help newbies like myself to start fresh and work from potential solutions.  Thank you pnuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISBLANK

```
=IF( ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1) , "A1 is blank" , "A1 is not blank" )
```